# python strip function is not giving expected output

Tags: python, csv

i have below code in which filenames are FR1.1.csv, FR2.0.csv etc. I am using these names to print in header row but i want to modify these name to FR1.1 , Fr2.0 and so on. Hence i am using strip function to remove .csv. when i have tried it at command prompt its working fine. But when i have added it to main script its not giving output.

```
for fname in filenames:
    print "fname     : ", fname
    fname.strip('.csv');
    print "after strip fname: ", fname
    headerline.append(fname+' Compile');
    headerline.append(fname+' Run');
```

output i am getting

```
fname     :FR1.1.csv
after strip fname: FR1.1.csv
```

required output-->

```
fname     :FR1.1.csv
after strip fname: FR1.1
```

i guess some indentation problem is there in my code after for loop.
plesae tell me what is the correct way to achive this.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This question shows research effort (he tried it on the command line where it worked, he provided his code, he showed what happened and what he would have expected) - not many questions attain this level of quality. So, welcome to StackOverflow, and don't get discouraged!

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks!!! I have started using python since last two weeks only. I know my question may be very simple for Experts. I am getting good support from this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable, so string methods can't change the original string, they return a new one which you need to assign again:

```
fname = fname.strip('.csv')   # no semicolons in Python!
```

But this call doesn't do what you probably expect it to. It will remove all the leading and trailing characters `c`, `s`, `v` and `.` from your string:

```
>>> "cross.csv".strip(".csv")
'ro'
```

So you probably want to do

```
import re
fname = re.sub(r"\.csv$", "", fname)
```

Comment: @RamMore: Thanks for accepting my answer, but you should really accept BartoszKP's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable. `strip()` returns a new string.

```
>>> "FR1.1.csv".strip('.csv')
'FR1.1'
>>> m = "FR1.1.csv".strip('.csv')
>>> print(m)
FR1.1
```

You need to do `fname = fname.strip('.csv')`.

And get rid of the semicolons in the end!

P.S - Please see Jon Clement's comment and Tim Pietzcker's answer to know why this code should not be used.

Answer (score 5):

You probably should use `os.path` for path manipulations:

```
import os

#...

for fname in filenames:
    print "fname     : ", fname
    fname = os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
    #...
```

The particular reason why your code fails is provided in other answers.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
fname.strip('.csv')
```

with

```
fname = fname.strip('.csv')
```